# Xpath - If else condition - Operation is always returning true

Tags: c#, selenium, bdd, specflow

My 'else if' statement is not getting triggered at all.

I have a dropdown which has 2 values. In the xpath the values are:

- P value = 0
- Q value = 1

The Value of **Time** is getting fetch from the Feature file

```
| Time |
| P    |
| T    |


public void SF(string Time)
    {
        var PXpathValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='PF']//option[@value='0']"));
        var QXpathValue = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='PF']//option[@value='1']"));

        IWebElement path = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//select[@id='PF']//*[contains(text(),'" + Time + "')]"));

        if ((path.Displayed) && (PXpathValue.Displayed))
        {
            Assert.That(path.Displayed, Is.True, "PF option is not displayed");
        }
        else if ((path.Displayed) && (QXpathValue.Displayed))
        {
            DropdownPF.Click();
            
            path.Click();
        }
        
        
    }
```

Any idea why the else if condition is not being triggered?

Comment: You are aware that if `path.Displayed` is `true` AND `PXpathValue.Displayed` is `true`… then `QXpathValue.Displayed` will never get evaluated.

Comment: I guess it's working as expected only. Because the drop-down value `PXpathValue` is always visible on `DOM`

Comment: Yes, right. Both values are displayed in DOM.

Comment: If both are visible then if condition will never fails. Whenever a drop-down value is selected you can see `@selected` value for that tag so create method or construct your xpath such way to verify. If you can post the `HTML` I can write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If this will return **true** `(path.Displayed) && (PXpathValue.Displayed)` which is a part of `if condition`, then it is obvious that it would not go to `else if`, that is functionality of **complier**.

**path** is a web element in your case, if that does not get displayed, you'd see NoSuchElement exception, in that case also it would not go to `else if`.

Solution is to use `findElements` instead of `findElement` which will return a list of web elements if found at least one, if not then list will be empty. In either way you wouldn't get any exception.

```
List<IWebElement> path = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//select[@id='PF']//*[contains(text(),'" + Time + "')]"));
```

Having said that you would not be able to use `.Displayed` on a list, you should check for size of the list if it's `>0` which should mean that the desired web element is captured if not then go to else if or else condition.